# Wrong permissions found on some files in home directory when doing backup

Tags: permissions, backup, launchpad-api, launchpadlib

I ran my first backup with Ubuntu 14.04 and it ended OK but reported a bunch of files that failed: these are all the ones in

```
/home/me/.launchpadlib/api.launchpad.net/cache
```

which must be more recent than Oct 9, 2013 because they are owned by root:root instead of me:me like the previous ones. I know I can exclude the whole folder from backup, but please tell me if I could safely get ownership over these files. The cache folder is owned by me:me and permissions are 700.

Is it a good idea to exclude this folder from backup?

Answer (score 1):

I just did

```
sudo chown me:me ~/.lauchpadlib/api.launchpad.net/cache/*
```

then re ran the backup and it ended without error. I don't know why the newer files were owned by root with `600` permission

Anyway, now I don't get errors grep[ping] -r pattern ~ or using baobab

Comment: You're probably getting an error because the target of the backup still has the old permissions and as non-root you won't be able to change them.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what's in the launchpad cache, but usually cache files can safely be deleted. They just store some temporary information, so that it does not have to be computed or downloaded every time you start your application.